# Where is the noun in this sentence

Tags: grammar, hyphens

Where is the noun in this sentence.

> You'll be really well rewarded in this job.

The reason why I wanna know that is because of this sentence “ That's right! The first adjective is an 'adverb + past participle' and it is after the noun, so we don't use hyphens.” but I couldn’t find noun in this sentence. Is it ‘you’ the noun or ‘be’? What is it??

Comment: Nouns are *things*.  Verbs are *actions* or *states of being*.  Best to understand the what a noun is before making the jump to adverb+past participle.  There are two *things* in your sentence.  Can you find the *things*?

Comment: The *first* noun is ***you***, which is syntactically required because it's the ***subject***. The *second* noun, ***job***, is just part of the ***optional*** adverbial clause ***in this job***.

Comment: Thanks all for teaching

Answer (score 0):

> ***You***'ll be really well rewarded in this ***job***.

All nouns in the sentence are highlighted and italicised. ("you" and "job")

---

Read more about nouns [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/nouns/)

> A noun is a word that names something, such as a person, place, thing, or idea. In a sentence, nouns can play the role of subject, direct object, indirect object, subject complement, object complement, appositive, or adjective.